# Application still uses deleted resources?

Tags: android, resources

I had a "layout-sw600dp" folder where I defined a layout which differed from the "default"-layout in the "layout" folder.
Now I've deleted the "layout-sw600dp" folder, but the device is still using this layout, even though it is removed from the project.

I cleared the cache, wiped the user data and of course reinstalled the app. It keeps using the layout-file from the removed "layout-sw600dp" folder.

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Default xml file? Drawable folder? Not sure if I get you right here, but there's only one xml-File left for this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning the device is useless. The problem is inside the APK. It's the IDE cache fault.

Try clean and rebuild the project to generate a new APK.

Comment: Rebuilding the project "Build" -> "Rebuild project" fixed the issue. Thanks :)